# How to manage Infopath VSTA code

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

**Situation**

We are currently developing a Sharepoint 2010 site that uses Infopath 2010 forms. However most of these forms require more advanced functionality thus these became Adminstrator-approved forms and have c# code on them (VSTA).

**Question**

Since each infopath form would have its own c# project, we are now having difficulties managing the code as more infopath forms are needed. Is there a better way to manage the code? Or is there a mechanism to have all of the VSTA code in one central location/solution?

Comment: There is no way I know of to use a Solution for multiple InfoPath VSTA projects. One InfoPath form with code beind = one project, rinse and repeat for the next form.

Comment: thanks, I had an idea whether to use a webservice for all the infopath forms to talk to, since Infopath can create Data Connections to web services. I would have the code all in one place, however I have a bad feeling that it would be hard to pass the data from the forms to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the InfoPath blog on how to manage InfoPath source code: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/06/10/using-tfs-for-source-control-in-infopath-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks, however would this mean that each infopath form would still have its own VSTA project?

Comment: Yes. You can't get around that. What I did once was to create a base class with all the common functions and then each form's VSTA contained a very basic C# file that derived from the base class. Not ideal but that's part of the reason InfoPath is not a true development environment.

Comment: Why the down vote? What's wrong with linking to a blog by the developers of InfoPath? Would you rather I regurgitated the contents here? Good grief.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was downvoted though, I appreciate your answer. Seeing that Infopath development has its drawbacks, what would be a better alternative (i.e. if possible to do away with Infopath)?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. InfoPath, IMO, is really good for simple forms (time off, expense etc) that do not require much complicated logic. Once you start needing VSTA, I would consider how much time it'll take to re-create all the form's layout, conditional logic etc in ASP.NET. That, for me, will be what decides whether I live with the pain of InfoPath development.

Comment: I think it depends on what your needs are and why you settled on InfoPath in the first place. If you did it because of the ease of designing forms, then you may be stuck with dealing with VSTA because InfoPath does make form creation easy (with conditional formatting, formulas, etc).

Comment: sorry for the double post. Accidentally click the "back" button and thot I lost my initial post. Anyway, both are valid. Consider the pros and cons (and in the cons section include the difficulty of maintaining InfoPath .xsn files since they are binary and not well suited for source control).

Comment: Yeah, right now we're experiencing the cons section pretty vividly. I'll have a think about this. Cheers.